# creating a random raster image using gdal

Tags: python, gdal, image, random

I want to create a random image containing say three classes with predefind percentages of each of the classes using gdal in python.

Can anyone provide any sample code?

Comment: I would suggest this is best done using R (see raster package), or any other scripting language with image capabilities such as Python, or Perl Data Language (PDL).

Answer (score 1):

See this example [Create raster from array](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-raster-from-array)

Replace the array with your own randomly created array. numpy.random as many random functions that you can use to construct the array as per your requirement